# Stack exchange login in Android app

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-exchange

I usually use Google login to login in stack exchange in browser. But there is no such option in Android app. So how do I login?

Where is the oauth login for Google?

Comment: Solved this. First went to login page and instead of using Google login, clicked forgot password, then created a password. As I have used Google login till now, there was no password associated with this account. So set the password and now works like a charm

Comment: It sounds like you just used a Stack Exchange OpenId instead of using Google- Which is a solid workaround, but isn't exactly a fix...

Comment: Atleast now I was able to login to Stack exchange Android app

Comment: Like I said, solid workaround. Glad you got it sorted out for yourself, at least!